# Understanding type variables in type annotations

Tags: types, elm, parametric-polymorphism, type-variables

The [Elm docs](https://guide.elm-lang.org/types/reading_types.html) illustrate type variables like this:

```
> List.reverse
<function> : List a -> List a
```

> ...the type variable a can vary depending on how List.reverse is used. But in this case, we have an a in the argument and in the result. This means that if you give a List Int you must get a List Int as well.

The docs for [Maybe.map](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Maybe#map) show this annotation:

```
map : (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
```

So why are the types annotated as `a` and `b` when they must be the same type?
I expected `a` to track the type i.e.:

```
map : (a -> a) -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So why are the types annotated as `a` and `b` when they must be the same type?

They don't! If `map` did use the same type variable for the input argument type and return type they would, but `map` can convert from one type to another. Here's a concrete example:

```
Maybe.map String.fromInt (Just 42)
```

`String.fromInt` has the type `Int -> String` and we use it as the first argument to `Maybe.map`. So if we try to substitute that in the of  `map`:

```
String.fromInt : (Int -> String)
Maybe.map      : (a   -> b     ) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
```

we see that `Int` substitutes `a` and `String` substitutes `b`. And therefore `Maybe a` has to be `Maybe Int` and `Maybe b` has to be `Maybe String`. Which means that if we try to give it a `Maybe String` instead:

```
Maybe.map String.fromInt (Just "foo")
```

we'll get an error:

```
The 2nd argument to `map` is not what I expect:

1 | foo = Maybe.map String.fromInt (Just "foo")
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^
This `Just` call produces:

    Maybe String

But `map` needs the 2nd argument to be:

    Maybe Int
```